# One checkbox not responding to events c# forms

Tags: c#

I have a problem its been bugging me for 2 days now.
Now the problem is that Uncertainty checkbox is not responding to events when  I click search.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;



 namespace THE_HELP
   {
   public partial class MainPanel : Form
{


    public MainPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSelectionSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            foreach (CheckBox chk in groupBox4.Controls)
            {
                chk.Checked = false;
                {
                    if (checkBoxCCF.Checked == true)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
                    }

                    else if (checkBoxReliabilty.Checked == true)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
                    }
                    else if (checkBoxRisk.Checked == true)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
                    }
                    else if (checkBoxSaftey.Checked == true)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4;
                    }
                    else if (checkBoxSensitivity.Checked == true)
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage5;
                    }
                    else if (checkBoxThroughput.Checked == true)
                    {

                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage6;
                    }
                    else if (checkBoxUncertainity.Checked == true)
                    {

                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage7;
                    }



                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkBoxReliabilty_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void groupBoxReliability_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
   }
```

[image]

CheckBox Uncertanity is not responding to events.

Comment: Why chk.Checked = false; ? You are unchecking everything and then checking if they are checked.

Comment: same question, why you have first line in `foreach` loop saying `chk.Checked = false;`. This should un-check every checkbox.

Comment: My idea was that if i check one box the other  do close.I use the tabbed box it only allows one tab to be viewed at a time.If you know how to show all tabs at once please show me.thanks

Comment: Remove `chk.Checked = false;` first and then debug your code. it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it like this

```
var checkbox = new CheckBox[] {checkBoxReliability, checkBoxRisks, ... };
var tab = new TabPage[] {tabPageReliability, tabPageRisks, ... };
for(int i = 0; i < checkbox.Length; i++)
    if(checkbox[i].Checked)
    {
         tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab[i];
         break;
    }
```

Comment: your code is Awesome thanks but is it possible to show all tabs if selected ?And also make tabbed box to appear only if checkboxes are clicked?

Comment: *to show all tabs if selected* - show all tabs where (tabcontrol can show only 1 tab at a time)? what is selected (checkbox checked?)? clarify please, try do describe what you want in a way what your mom will read and will understand.

Comment: If the user clicks all checkboxes is it possible to show all of the tabs below.My second question is when i run the program i only want to see the Features part only after i have clicked the search button

Comment: You have one `TabControl` and it can display only one `TabPage`. I can't understand what would be *show all of the all tabs*. Make more `TabControl`s ? And regarding second question, run this code in button click event (not in timer of whatever), so that it will be shown *only after i have clicked the search button*.